# Minecraft forge 1.8 wont load texture even though it is in the right folder

Tags: png, textures, minecraft, minecraft-forge

i am new to minecraft 1.8 modding and was following along with mrcrayfish's tutorial but my mod does not load the texture on an item called ref_copper. i think it may have to do with png colour settings or permissions. Anyway here is a screanshot of what i mean https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDTv5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've named something 'item' that should be named 'items'. If you look in your screenshot on the left, it says textures.item, whereas the error is looking for the file in textures/items/.

In the video you're referencing [here](https://youtu.be/2_qM-Z0IQ4k?t=913), you can see that it looks like textures.items for the narrator.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, worked great

Comment: Thank you for answering and contributing to Stack Overflow, however please take a second look at the question, for it seems to be off-topic according to the [help/on-topic]. Answering off-topic question make it look like it's okay to ask such questions - it's not. Off-topic questions might get closed and then deleted, which would nullify your contribution!

Comment: When people like you stop voting me down and I can finally comment on posts, I will tell people as much in comments while still answering their question. Until then I'm using the tools I have.